# Nesting an image in Nav Bar using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am working on a web project for school, which brings me to a dead end at the moment. I am currently building a navigation bar for my pages and I am looking to nest a logo image to the inside left portion of the navbar. Any suggestions would be great!

Note:  I apologize ahead of time, I could not figure out jsfiddle. Too many dang errors.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: lightblue;
}
small {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 40px;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: inherit;
  padding: 50px;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
section {
  height: 50vh;
}
/* NAVIGATION */

nav {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #d67ca8;
  padding: .25px 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px #dedede;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 1px;
}
nav ul li a,
nav ul li a:after,
nav ul li a:before {
  transition: all .5s;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #555;
}
/* stroke */

nav.stroke ul li a,
nav.fill ul li a {
  position: relative;
}
nav.stroke ul li a:after,
nav.fill ul li a:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0%;
  content: '.';
  color: transparent;
  background: #aaa;
  height: 1px;
}
nav.stroke ul li a:hover:after,
nav.stroke ul li a.active:after {
  width: 100%;
}
nav.fill ul li a {
  transition: all 2s;
}
nav.fill ul li a:after {
  text-align: left;
  content: '.';
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
nav.fill ul li a:hover,
nav.fill ul li a.active {
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}
nav.fill ul li a:hover:after,
nav.fill ul li a.active:after {
  z-index: -10;
  animation: fill 1s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: fill 1s forwards;
  -moz-animation: fill 1s forwards;
  opacity: 1;
}
/* Keyframes */

@-webkit-keyframes fill {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
    height: 1px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #333;
  }
}
/* IMAGES */

#navlogo {}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Title | Home</title>

  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,900,100,300,700,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="icon" type="text/css" sizes="32x32" href="images/favicon1-32x32.png" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

</head>

<body>

  <nav class="fill">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img id="navlogo" src="images/logo-72x72.png"></img>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Downloads</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">More</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `margin-right:50px;` ?

Comment: it moves it a bit but for some reason it seems as though the image creates too much padding(?)  to my liking... Is there a way to auto the image into the current nav sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I change some HTML code which is not proper and some style to make exact 
you want.

I hope this code will help you.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: lightblue;
}
small {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 40px;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: inherit;
  padding: 50px;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
section {
  height: 50vh;
}
/* NAVIGATION */

.logo{
  float: left;
  max-width: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height:50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.logo a{
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.logo a img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
nav {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #d67ca8;
  padding: .25px 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px #dedede;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 1px;
}
nav ul li a,
nav ul li a:after,
nav ul li a:before {
  transition: all .5s;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #555;
}
/* stroke */

nav.stroke ul li a,
nav.fill ul li a {
  position: relative;
}
nav.stroke ul li a:after,
nav.fill ul li a:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 0%;
  content: '.';
  color: transparent;
  background: #aaa;
  height: 1px;
}
nav.stroke ul li a:hover:after,
nav.stroke ul li a.active:after {
  width: 100%;
}
nav.fill ul li a {
  transition: all 2s;
}
nav.fill ul li a:after {
  text-align: left;
  content: '.';
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
nav.fill ul li a:hover,
nav.fill ul li a.active {
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}
nav.fill ul li a:hover:after,
nav.fill ul li a.active:after {
  z-index: -10;
  animation: fill 1s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: fill 1s forwards;
  -moz-animation: fill 1s forwards;
  opacity: 1;
}
/* Keyframes */

@-webkit-keyframes fill {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
    height: 1px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #333;
  }
}
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Title | Home</title>
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,900,100,300,700,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <link rel="icon" type="text/css" sizes="32x32" href="images/favicon1-32x32.png" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <nav class="fill">
        <ul>
            <div class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo-72x72.png"></a></div>
            <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! Thank you for your time and effort!

Answer (score 0):

Not likely to  fix your issue - but in the interest of teaching - you are trying to nest a series of li's inside another one - this is not correct - you need to nest a UL inside the li. - also img tags are self closing so you us /> and also you should add an ALT text to all of your image (and also size attributes..

Note that I do not recommend doing this way - but to answer your query regarding nesting - it is fine to nest a ul with li's inside an li - but not naked li's on their own.

```
  <nav class="fill">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img id="navlogo" src="images/logo-72x72.png" alt ="logo" width="72"  height ="72"/>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Thank you @gav for your helpful information however, the image is now centered above the nav links... I am still dumbfound that i cannot align the bottom of the image with the botttom of the text as well as to the left of the nav bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img id="navlogo" class = "brand" src="images/logo-72x72.png"></img>
```

add name for class eg:brand and,try this

```
.brand {height: 25px;}
```